# Is it worth to create a pure graphics library for haskell

Tags: graphics, haskell, functional-programming

I am quite new to Haskell, but there is some idea, I have. I would like to know if it's worth to implement it (if it's consistent with recommended Haskell style and if it isn't already done).

I am thinking about a library that would feature a pure, abstract canvas object. It would work like this:

1. The object would be immutable. Drawing on it would create a new canvas (implemented as list construction).
2. It would be completely abstract list of shapes independent from any actual renderer.
3. There will be renderers able to transform this abstract canvas to bitmap and vector formats. This would be the only impure operation needed when working with this library.

What do you think? If I receive approval from some seasoned haskellist I would give it a try.

Comment: This would perhaps be a better topic for a haskell-cafe thread, since it's so open-ended...

Comment: Hard to give approval for a project that you haven't started yet. If you're going to complete a buggy prototype and then give up like what happens with most projects, don't bother unless you're doing it's just for your own experience.

Comment: Check out the Diagrams library: http://projects.haskell.org/diagrams/

Comment: @amidndfv - this is actually an answer to my question. Thanks.

Comment: Also check out [Pan](http://conal.net/Pan).